# PHP Laravel: Any sort of package or way to active live log while doing php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

I've been working in ruby/rails for a while now and just recently switched up to PHP Laravel for my new work position. 
In rails, when I would run my server it would show me very useful things such as: which route is getting hit, what queries ran for that controller and so on.

On Laravel when when I run a server all it says 
`Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>`
and it just sits there.

Is there some composer package or something I don't know about that I have to switch on in the config to show some kind of relevant information while routes are being hit???

I've been googling up 'laravel live log' and stumbled across this package 
https://packagist.org/packages/mic/log-like-rails
But I can't seem to install it correctly.

Laravel Framework 5.6.22
PHP 7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: That package is very old and for Laravel 4.2, so it's not surprising you can't install it on 5.6.   Laravel Debug Bar has a lot of useful information and isn't restricted to using `artisan serve` as many people run homestead, wamp/xampp/laragon, or another dev environment.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can run `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`. This uses the same built-in webserver of PHP as `artisan serve`, but this way each URL you hit is displayed on stdout, ie. in your terminal

Comment: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` is really good step up, thank you. I was hoping more for like a package or some kind of hidden dev feature that I needed to turn on but after doing a 2h research yesterday I don't think there's nothing of the sort of what I'm looking for. 

Thanks again for all replies.